# Equations of the tangents to the curve $f(x) = 2x^2 + 3$

Tags: derivatives

Find the equations of the tangents to the curve $f(x) = 2x^2 + 3$ that pass through the point $(2,3)$. Include a sketch as part of your solution.

First, I found the derivative of $f(x)$ which is $4x$, but I'm not sure what to do next.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Any point on the curve $y=f(x)$ is of the form $\langle a,2a^2+3\rangle$, and the slope of the tangent line at that point is, as you discovered, $4a$. Write down the equation of the straight line of slope $4a$ passing through the point $\langle a,2a^2+3\rangle$, then choose $a$ so that this line also passes through the point $\langle 2,3\rangle$.

Comment: Would the equation of the straight line of slope 4a passing through the point (a, 2a^2 + 3) be 2a^2 + 3 = (4a)a?

Comment: @user148748: That can’t be: its equation will have the form $y=mx+b$ for some constants $m$ and $b$ (which will depend on $a$).

Answer (score 0):

Observe that a straight $g$ through $(2,3)$ has the form $g(x)=mx +3-2m$.  Now determine all $m$ for which $f(x)=g(x)$ possesses exactly one solution.

Comment: The downvote was what for?